# Creating & mapping user home folders on a network share using GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have deployed a fileserver which has had its harddrive partioned to include a shared partition along with a shared folder within it. The fileserver has joined my domain, hosted on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server, and I can access any resource through my network.
The problems begin when I try to create and apply my GPO. I created a new GPO that uses a drive map to the path `\\fileserver\Homes\%username%`, which is the location that I want to store my user folders in.
The GPO is set to Action: **Create**, **Run in logged-on user's security context**, as well as having the previously mentioned path set. These are the only things that I edited in my GPO.

I would like to note that I can create maps to each user successfully, using the **profile** tab in each user object, but I want to be able to solve this task using a GPO.

To put it simply; my GPO does not seem to do anything. Is there anything obvious that I am missing in my configuration?

Comment: Where is the GPO linked?

Comment: GPOs for mapping drives do *not* create folders. That's what the "folder redirection" policies are for.

Answer (score 1):

The variable in GPO for username is LogonUser. So try changing the drive mapping to

```
\\fileserver\Homes\%LOGONUSER%
```

Comment: and if you have multiple domains %userdnsdomain% would do the job also foe the domain part